# Can't determine candelabra type bulb

Tags: electrical

This bulb came out of my Harbor Breeze ceiling fan and I'm not sure what type candelabra it is. I can't find manual. 
One time I bought a bulb at Lowes but it was wrong type but I don't remember what type that was. Aye,aye,aye!

[image]

Comment: If you search *fan bulb candelabra base* you will find sources for this A15 type bulb.

Comment: Candelabra is the most common type of base there is, after Edison E26/27.  By "commom" I mean LED bulbs are readily available and at sane price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very cleverest thing to do is to take the bulb in the picture with you to the store so you can compare it with the replacements that they have on the rack.

It can be a good idea to place the bulb in some type of paper bag wrapped in a paper towel when you transport and handle it so in case there is an accident of some sort and it gets broken there is not glass flying all over your car or the parking lot.

Answer (score 1):

Harbor Breeze is Lowes' house brand for the cheapies they import from China.  Lowes will be the canonical place to go for those bulbs.  However expect them to streamline their inventory of incandescent bulbs somewhat ( while dropping CFLs entirely), and possibly discontinue that bulb if it's an oddball.  Next I would try online such as 1000bulbs.com.

Long term, start shopping for an LED screw-in that you think you will like.

Comment: I agree with Harper. Just switch to an LED with a candelabra base. It will be low wattage and never hot and will have a plastic globe.